# How to hide blank rows in a Powerpoint table using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new to VBA macros and trying to write a macro to hide the blank rows in a Powerpoint table. I'm not sure which properties to use and how to move on.

```
Sub TableRowHide()

Dim sl as Slide
Dim shTable as Shape
Dim pres as Presentation
Dim irow as Integer
Dim icol as Integer
Dim counter as Integer

Set pres = ActivePresentation

With sh.Table

  For irow = 1 to .Rows.Count
     counter = 0
   For icol = 1 to .Columns.Count

   If shTable.table.Cell(irow,icol).Shape.Textframe.Textrange.Text = "" 
     Then --------------

     counter = counter + 1
     End If

     If counter = .Columns.Count Then --------

      Else   ------------

   Next icol

   Next irow

  End With

   End Sub
```

Comment: Don't think it's possible to hide rows in PowerPoint...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to delete the row. There's no method for hiding it in PowerPoint.  If you need to preserve the original table, perhaps make a copy of it, set the original's .Visible property to False then modify the copy.

Here's a way of going about it. General idea:  for each row, accumulate the text from each of the cells in the row into a temporary string. If the length of the string is 0, then it's a blank row ... delete it.

In order for it to work, you must step backwards through the rows, otherwise the internal For/Next counter gets out of synch when you delete a row.

Option Explicit
' Always start with this; saves a world of trouble, keeps you honest

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()

    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim sTemp As String

    Set oTbl = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Table

    With oTbl

        For lRow = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            sTemp = ""
            For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                sTemp = sTemp & .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
            Next
            If Len(sTemp) = 0 Then
                .Rows(lRow).Delete
            End If
        Next    ' row

    End With    ' oTbl

End Sub
```